# Format telephone numbers for values

Tags: views, webforms, 9

I have created a webform with telephone field, the submitted data is displayed in a views table, however the numbers in submitted data are in random format such as 1234567890, 234-987-9870, how do I configure the number field in views to be displayed in (123) 123 1234 format for the existing values and new submission.

Comment: Does this work with Views? https://www.drupal.org/project/telephone_formatter

Comment: @cilefen, there is no view format options for the module

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Jquery here is a solution:

$('.phone').text(function(i, text) {
return text.replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '$1-$2-$3');
});

http://jsfiddle.net/Xxk3F/1/

Answer found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760070/how-to-format-a-phone-number-with-jquery